# How to convert moment.js date format 'LLL' to 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How can i change format of moment.js date?
I use locales format ('LLL') in datatables columnDefs render and trying to filter date column with external filter inputs.
When i format input value with 'LLL', logical operators doesn't work correct. So maybe if i convert column data, it will work.
Theese are my codes:

```
"render": function (data) {
                        var locale = lang;
                        return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).locale(locale).format("LLL") : "-";
```

and filtering is:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
                var filterstart = $('#start').val();
                var filterend = $('#end').val();
                var datecolumn = 5;
                var tabledatestart = aData[datecolumn];
                var tabledateend = aData[datecolumn];

                var locale = lang;
                filterstart = (moment(filterstart).isValid()) ? moment(filterstart).locale(locale).format('LLL') : "";
                filterend = (moment(filterend).isValid()) ? moment(filterend).locale(locale).format('LLL') : "";

                if (filterstart === "" && filterend === "") {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((filterstart==tabledatestart || filterstart<tabledatestart) && filterend === "") {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((filterstart==tabledatestart || filterstart>tabledatestart) && filterstart === "") {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((filterstart==tabledatestart || filterstart<tabledatestart) && (filterend==tabledateend || filterend>tabledateend)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );
```

Comment: What is the format `LLL`? Please may you provide some examples?

Comment: @evolutionxbox LLL format is like 'January 6, 2022 12:45 PM'

Comment: Would it be `moment('January 6, 2022 12:45 PM', 'LLL').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @evolutionxbox this works thanks a lot. But when the date locale is Turkey, doesnt work. Turkish date seems like '6 Ocak 2022 12:45'

Comment: Are you using moment with locales? (Like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js) and have you set the locale first? `moment.locale('tr_TR')`

Comment: Yes that's right. To summarize, I take the user language option from the cookies and format the date with locales according to this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use [moment with locales](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js) and set the locale before parsing the date.

```js
moment.locale('tr_TR');

console.log(
  moment('6 Ocak 2022 12:45', 'LLL').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

I'm pretty sure that the locale needs to be set first *before parsing*, as the following returns `'Invalid Date'`:

```js
console.log(
  moment('6 Ocak 2022 12:45', 'LLL').locale('tr_TR').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was type locale while setting the variable. This is working now.

Comment: This is working for filtering. But column order in datatables not working when locale is tr_TR (i mean manual ordering by clickling column name). I am working on it now.

Comment: @nurullahiris that might need a different question

Comment: I solved it too. Thank you again